# Modx phpthumbof have no effect on image

Tags: modx, phpthumb

```
<img src = "[[+tv.img:phpthumbof=`w=180&h=150`]]">
```

This construction returns image with original size

1. I tried create phpthumbof/cache with 777
2. I tried reinstall phpthumbof
3. ImageMagick installed in php
4. "phpthumb:...allow...docroot..." enabled in config
5. I tried "pthumb", but same result

Comment: Any errors in apache logs? Modx logs? Tried test same code on free https://modxcloud.com/ plan ?

Comment: No errors in apache logs, modx will check, ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the way you are attempting to use it could be the issue, you can either try:

```
<img src = "[[!phpthumbof? &input=`[[+tv.img]]` &options=`&w=180&h=150`]]">
```

Or change your TV output type to  "image" then:

```
[[+tv.img:phpthumbof=`w=180&h=150`]]
```

Should work.

I think what might be happening is that your TV output is just the path & phpthumbof can't do anything with just the path it needs the actual image as input ~ so it's just getting ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version MODX you are using. But this is how I usually do it:

```
<img src="[[*myimagetv:phpthumbof=`w=180&h=150`]]">
```

**myimagetv TV**

Input type: **image**

Output type: **text**

*Note:* if your tag is inside a chunk template called by a snippet, then the asterisk should be a plus sign instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpthumbof on a subfolder on your webserver than phpthumbof uses internally the wrong path.

For example: 
Your document root ist yourdomain.de and points to /var/www/htdocs/yourdomain.de

Your MODX-Installation is in the subfolder /var/www/htdocs/yourdomain.de/test/

You edit your MODX-test-"domain" with yourdomain.de/test/manager.
-> everything is working as expected (phpthumbof not)

if you create a new subdomain aka test.yourdomain.de as a real document root und map this domain to your subfolder /var/www/htdocs/yourdomain.de/test/ phpthumbof is working as expected!

Keep in mind to clear the MODX-Cache before changing and to modify the file core/config/config.inc.php (only the entries with relative paths!)

Oliver